# Using Stanford NER for extracting Address from a text document?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, text-processing

I was looking Stanford [NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) and thinking of using JAVA Apis it to extract postal address from a text document. The document may be any document where there is an postal address section e.g. Utility Bills, electricity bills.

So what I am thinking as the approach is,

1. Define postal address as a named entity using LOCATION and other primitive named entities.
2. Define segmentation and other sub process.

I am trying to find a example pipeline for the same (what are the steps in details required), anyone has done this before? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Do you have a training set of addresses in text?

Comment: @GaborAngeli Yes, I do have addresses in text for a country but not labelled properly with respect to zip, city, addressline1, addressline2.

Comment: In that case, my recommendation is to either collect a dataset of addresses tagged in text, and then train something like the Stanford NER system. Or, build some heuristic rule-based system off of a combination of Stanford NER and TokensRegexNER.

Comment: @GaborAngeli I like the idea of tagging addresses in text. My question now is, should I divide addresses into multiple parts, e.g. {city, zip, line1, line 2} and somehow define a compound entity with respect to existing defined named entity LOCATION or define address as a new entity with some lose structure? Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'd imagine you can only win by separating the address into different components; it gives the hidden states of the sequence model more to work off of in terms of the structure of an address, and lets each class handle a narrower range of words. If nothing else, you can collapse the states easily and try it out. On the other hand, it's also more annotation effort, and quite possibly won't make a huge difference. How many sentences do you intend to tag?

Comment: @GaborAngeli thanks. Yes, Separating looks promising but  The document will be ~100 lines long and the address is in multiple consecutive lines (1-6). why do you say "quite possibly won't make a huge difference" ?

Comment: @GaborAngeli also can you write in an answer ? Thanks.

Comment: @yadab I am trying to solve the similar problem and I am training an NER model using spacy. I need labeled training set if you have can please share with me?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear: all credit goes to Raj Vardhan (and John Bauer) who had an interaction on the [[java-nlp-user]](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2014-February/005003.html) mailing list.

Raj Vardhan wrote about the plan to work on "finding street address in a sentence":

> Here is an approach I have thought of:
>
> 1. Find the *event-anchor* in a sentence
> 2. Select outgoing-edges in the *SemanticGraph* from that event-node
>      with relations such as *"prep-in" *or *"prep-at".*
> 3. IF the dependent value in the relation has POS tag as NNP
>
> a)    Find outgoing-edges from dependent value's node with relations such
>   as *"nn"*
>
> b)    Connect all such nodes in increasing order of occurrence in the
>   sentence.
>
> c)    PRINT resulting value as Location where the event occurred
>
> This is obviously with certain assumptions such as direct dependency
>   between the event-anchor and location in a sentence.

Not sure whether this could help you, but I wanted to mention it just in case. Again, any credit should go to Raj Vardhan (and John Bauer).

Comment: thanks. I am going to try out this as well but if the location is spread across multiple line, segmentation is becoming little bit tricky. I will update with my findings.

Comment: @yadab how did you make out with this?  I am looking to do something similar and don't want to reinvent the wheel.