# i want extract address using regex in python where i can use a lookbehind so that i get the preceding 3-4 strings that hold the address

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, python-2.7

```
text = ' My uncle is admitted in the hospital. the address of the hospital is \n Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '
```

now i am using this as my regex expression but just getting 'Hills' and not getting the required output.

```
re.findall(r'(\w\S+\s+)(?=Hyderabad){3}'
```

My desired output is - ' Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '

I want to write a regex expression which can help me extract 3 to 4 strings prior to the city name like 'Hyderabad' in this case, and whether special characters are presend or not present in the raw string.

Comment: That's not 3 to 4 strings, that's 6 strings.  This is not a job for a regex.  You can split the string by words. look for Hyderabad, then back up until you find a word that doesn't start with a capital letter.

Comment: What determines how far you want to go back? Is there a rule that says what counts as part of the address? What distinguishes `"is"` from `"Apollo"` in your example? Are you sure that won't give false results on some other input?

Comment: Will 6 digit PINCODE always be there?

Comment: as others pointed out, regex is not a good tool for this job, splitting the string on spaces and going from there is the better option. If you insist, something like this should work: `(\b[A-Z]\w+,? ){3,}Hyderabad - \d{3} \d{3}\.` (adjust the digit stuff at the end)

Comment: @anubhava YES 6 DIGIT PIN CODE WILL ALWAYS BE THERE.

Comment: Is there a regex expression possible where i can get all the strings prior to the six digit pincode just before \n (new line character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [**deque**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

text = ' My uncle is admitted in the hospital. the address of the hospital is Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '

def guess_address(needle, string):
    stack, started = [], False
    de = deque(string.split())

    while de:
        word = de.pop()
        if word == needle:
            stack.append(word)
            started = True
        elif started and word[0].isupper():
            stack.append(word)
        elif started and word[0].islower():
            break

    return stack[::-1]

stack = guess_address('Hyderabad', text)
print(stack)
```

Which yields

```
['Apollo', 'Health', 'City', 'Campus,', 'Jubilee', 'Hills,', 'Hyderabad']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why regular expressions are most probably a wrong approach

As [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) noted above - it is not a problem that can be best handled using regex. It requires a much more powerful tool than that just a regular expression.

You can see the approaches used for identifying addresses and splitting them into elements like street address, city, zip code, etc. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780549/6573902). I hope it can shed some light onto the complexity of this problem.

Your example suggests that what you are in fact trying to do is [extraction of information](https://www.ontotext.com/knowledgehub/fundamentals/information-extraction/) on entities like hospitals and /  or their addresses. This can be handled using a [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) tool trained to detect such entities in text.

#### How to construct lookahead regex

If you use the following regex:

```
r'((\w\S+\s+){1,6})(?=Hyderabad){3}'
```

it will extract what you want:

> Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills,

Please see a [test example](https://pythex.org/?regex=((%5Cw%5CS%2B%5Cs%2B)%7B1%2C6%7D)(%3F%3DHyderabad)%7B3%7D&test_string=My%20uncle%20is%20admitted%20in%20the%20hospital.%20the%20address%20of%20the%20hospital%20is%20Apollo%20Health%20City%20Campus%2C%20Jubilee%20Hills%2C%20Hyderabad%20-%20500%20033.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) here. Please note, that the part of interest is the first matching group - not the text matched in its entirety.

Comment: thanks a lot, but Is there a regex expression possible where i can get all the strings prior to the six digit pincode just before \n (new line character). ?

Comment: @guatidibba: it is possible to create such a regex but it is a different question to me. Please post it separately and accept this answer as it seems that it answers your initial question.